# Linear Programming implementation in R

Tags: r, linear-programming

Hi I need to implement the following linear programming equations to be solved using R. I didn't find useful resources to implement it. Please help

Objective function

```
25 Sc + 10 Sw + 5Ss + 21 Ac + 6 Aw + 1As + 25 Wc + 10 Ww + 5Ws
```

following are the constraint functions

```
Sc + Sw + Ss <= 4500
0.5Sc-0.5Sw-0.5Ss>=0   
-0.3Sc+0.7Sw-0.3Ss>=0
Ac + Aw + As <= 4000
0.4Ac-0.6Aw-0.6As>=0
-0.4Ac+0.6Aw-0.4As>=0
Wc + Ww + Ws <=4000
0.6Wc-0.4Ww-0.4Ws>=0
-0.5Wc+0.5Ww-0.5Ws>=0
```

I need this to be solved using R. A normal implementation is possible to be tried out. But I'm confused with this on. How can I prepare the matrix.

Comment: I like the `lpSolveAPI` package for this kind of tasks. You can find some example to get started here: https://gigadom.in/tag/lpsolveapi/